# How to find the path that a recursive function took using c#?

Tags: c#, recursion

I have an object which has a property to allow me to create another instance of the same object (nested object.) I need to search a list and find out the first occurrence of an object in the nest.

Once one is found, I want to find out the exact path it took to find it.

I have the following class

```
public class ReportRelationMapping : IReportRelationMapping
{
    string Name { get; set; }

    IReportRelation LocalRelation { get; set; }

    IReportRelation ForeignRelation { get; set; }

    IReportRelationMapping RelatedThrough { get; set; } // This creates and instance of itself creating a chain
}
```

Assume I have the following list of the above class

```
List<IReportRelationMapping> myList = new List<ReportRelationMapping> 
{
    new ReportRelationMapping 
    {
        Name = "A",
        LocalRelation = ..., 
        ForeignRelation = ...
        RelatedThrough = new ReportRelationMapping
        {
            Name = "B",
            LocalRelation = ..., 
            ForeignRelation = ...
            RelatedThrough = new ReportRelationMapping
            {
                Name = "C",
                LocalRelation = ..., 
                ForeignRelation = ...
                RelatedThrough = new ReportRelationMapping
                {
                    Name = "D",
                    LocalRelation = ..., 
                    ForeignRelation = ...
                    RelatedThrough = new ReportRelationMapping
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ,new ReportRelationMapping 
    {
        Name = "E",
        LocalRelation = ..., 
        ForeignRelation = ...
        RelatedThrough = new ReportRelationMapping
        {
            Name = "F",
            LocalRelation = ..., 
            ForeignRelation = ...

        }
    }
    ,new ReportRelationMapping 
    {
        Name = "G",
        LocalRelation = ..., 
        ForeignRelation = ...
    }
}
```

I need to find out the exact path it took to find the first "C". I need to get the following list

```
List<ReportRelationMapping> pathToTarget = new List<ReportRelationMapping> 
{
    new ReportRelationMapping 
    {
        Name = "A",
        LocalRelation = ..., 
        ForeignRelation = ...
    }
    ,new ReportRelationMapping 
    {
        Name = "B",
        LocalRelation = ..., 
        ForeignRelation = ...
    }
    ,new ReportRelationMapping 
    {
        Name = "C",
        LocalRelation = ..., 
        ForeignRelation = ...
    }
}
```

I wrote a recurive method that will find "C" correctly but it does not capture the path it took correctly.
Here is what I have done

```
private void GetAvailableRelation(List<IReportRelationMapping> relationsMappings, string belongsTo, ref List<IReportRelationMapping> pathToTarget)
{

    var requiredRelation = relationsMappings.Where(x => x.LocalRelation.TableAlias == belongsTo || x.ForeignRelation.TableAlias == belongsTo).FirstOrDefault();

    if (requiredRelation == null)
    {
        //At this point we know there is no match on the top level, lets check the nested level
        var relatedRelations = new List<IReportRelationMapping>();

        foreach (var relationsMapping in relationsMappings)
        {
            if (relationsMapping.RelatedThrough != null)
            {
                relatedRelations.Add(relationsMapping.RelatedThrough);
            }
        }

        if (relatedRelations.Any())
        {
            GetAvailableRelation(relatedRelations, belongsTo, ref pathToTarget);
        }
        else
        {
            // Since we reached the last node and count not find a matching, reset the pathToTarget list
            pathToTarget.Clear();
        }
    }

    if (requiredRelation != null)
    {
        //Check if relation exists before adding it.
        pathToTarget.Add(requiredRelation);
    }

}


The problem seems to be that after I call the method `GetAvailableRelation` recursively, the value of `requiredRelation` will become `null` when the last line come there is nothing to add to my `pathToTarget`.
```

**Question:** How can I generate `pathToTarget` list correctly?

Comment: addup the compound relations as you go... so depending on what you want.. you would want instead of return requiredrelation at the end, to add the results of getavailablerelation to your list... so while your current one would find an option by the time your iteration came out, you'd probably have a null because you and passing it back.. if that makes sense.

Comment: But some how I would need to reset that list incase "C" was not found in the first node. How would I know that this is the very first node in the list? If I don't reset the list somehow I would think I would get all the object top to bottom until one is found

Comment: As stated, the question is too broad. Without a good [mcve], you are asking answerers to implement the entire program, not just the little part you need help with, and the question shows no evidence of you having done any research on the topic yourself. Look into recursive path-finding algorithms that return e.g. lists of directions or nodes visited. The basic idea is that you need each level of recursion to return its current node, added to the list of all nodes returned by the recursive call that level made.

Comment: You can start here: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+recursion+list+of+nodes. You might find your answer in there, or at least ideas for how to research your question further.

Comment: I updated my question to show exactly what I have done. I can find "C" with no problem but the path is not being captured correctly. The list `pathToTarget` will only have the "C" when the method finish executing.

Comment: Because you only prepend it to child returns that arent null

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer: stop mutating things.

You are passing in a reference to a variable that is itself a reference to a mutable list, and are then mutating the latter. This is a recipe for confusion in recursive code. (You never mutate the reference; **why are you passing the variable by ref if you are never going to mutate it???** I think you may have a fundamental misunderstanding of reference semantics in C#.)

Instead, reason as follows. Begin with the fundamentals:

- My function has inputs and outputs
- The outputs depend solely upon the inputs
- The inputs and outputs are never mutated

OK, now think: given that you have chosen to follow these rules, what must the inputs and outputs be? The input is an immutable sequence of something. The output is an immutable sequence of something. Great.

Since this is a recursive method, we know the following additional facts:

- There will be a simple base case where we detect that the solution is trivial, and return the trivial solution.
- There will be a recursive case where we divide the problem into smaller problems, solve them recursively, and the combine the recursive solutions into a solution to the larger problem.

Now you can answer these questions:

- What should the argument types of my method be?
- What should the return types of my method be?
- What is the trivial case?
- How do I break down a non-trivial case into one or more simpler problems?
- How do I combine the solutions of those problems into a solution to the larger problem?

Let's sketch out some answers:

- The method takes an immutable sequence of items and a search item.
- The method returns an immutable sequence of items which is a path.
- There are two trivial cases. Case one is: the current sequence of items contains *only* the search item. The trivial solution is the path containing *only* the matching item.  Case two is: the current sequence of items is empty. The trivial solution is that the path is empty.
- The recursive case is: find a simpler problem and solve it; this gives back a path. If the path is empty, then return an empty path, because that means the item was not found. Otherwise, prepend the current item to the path and return it.

Now can you write your method?

Comment: I think I got it to work. I tried to follow your advise here and it seems to be working as expected. please take a look at my answer. Please let me know if you still see an issue there.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to derecursive your code using a temporary object to simulate the stack, when you will find your object, that stack will contain the exact path to it.

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved the problem by trying to follow the rules that were listed in the correct answer by Eric Lippert.

Here is the function which seems to be working.

```
    private List<IReportRelationMapping> GetAvailableRelation(List<IReportRelationMapping> relationsMappings, string belongsTo)
    {
        List<IReportRelationMapping> pathToTarget = new List<IReportRelationMapping>();

        var requiredRelation = relationsMappings.Where(x => x.LocalRelation.TableAlias == belongsTo || x.ForeignRelation.TableAlias == belongsTo).FirstOrDefault();

        if (requiredRelation != null)
        {
            //Handle the top level

            pathToTarget.Add(requiredRelation);

        } else {
            //At this point we know there is no match on the top level, lets check the nested level

            var relatedRelations = new List<IReportRelationMapping>();

            foreach (var relationsMapping in relationsMappings)
            {
                if (relationsMapping.RelatedThrough != null)
                {
                    //Add the path in between previous and next
                    pathToTarget.Add(relationsMapping);

                    foreach (var subRelation in relationsMapping.RelatedThrough)
                    {
                        relatedRelations.Add(subRelation);
                    }

                }
            }

            if (relatedRelations.Any())
            {
                //Now we know there is at least one more nested level that we need to check
                var subPathsToTarget = GetAvailableRelation(relatedRelations, belongsTo);

              if (subPathsToTarget.Any())
                {
                    //prepend the current items to the path
                    pathToTarget = pathToTarget.Concat(subPathsToTarget).ToList();
                }
                else
                {
                    //At this point we know we reach the final node and the item was not found.
                    pathToTarget.Clear();
                }

            }

        }

        return pathToTarget;

    }
```

**UPDATED**

now my object accepts a list for `RelatedThrough` like this

```
public class ReportRelationMapping : IReportRelationMapping
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public SqlJoinStatement JoinType { get; set; }

    public IReportRelation LocalRelation { get; set; }

    public IReportRelation ForeignRelation { get; set; }

    public List<IReportRelationMapping> RelatedThrough { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Looks pretty reasonable.  Now ask yourself: can I make it better?  For example: why does the argument have to be a List?  You do nothing list-like with it except call Where and iterate over it with ForEach. That thing could be an IEnumerable; it need not be a List.

Comment: Similarly: why does the return type have to be List?  Why isn't it just IEnumerable also?  All you do with the return value is call Concat and ToList on it; the thing that is returned never has any other operation done to it. So you could make it IEnumerable as well, and eliminate the ToList.

Comment: Actually there is one problem after doing more testing with it. The problem is that the middle relation gets added whether or not the final relation is found. somehow the following line path `pathToTarget.Add(relationsMapping);` should be removed if the final note was not found.

Comment: Never mind I figure that out. I had to clear `pathToTarget` list if the lower search returned empty data set.

Comment: The reason I left everything to be a list for now is because I am thinking to change the way I construct the object. I am thinking to make `RelatedThrough` as a list. But once I am done making the changes I will revisit the method and clean it up.

Comment: I encourage you to stop thinking about "clearing lists" and the like. Read my answer again: your ability to write bug-free code will improve when you stop thinking about lists as things you can mutate, and start thinking of them as immutable objects that you can apply sequence operators to.